# divide double in vb.net is wrong

Tags: vb.net, algorithm

iam using this function in my program vb.net

```
Public Function getmeter(ByVal metersize As Double) As Double
        Dim result As Double
        Dim remain As Double = metersize / size
        SplitDouble(remain)
        result = Calcuatedemeter(cartons, plateNum)

        Return result
    End Function
```

while iam giving this Value 
metersize =1365.28
size=1.61
the result should be 848 i test it in my calculator and in sci-calculator in google calculator and duckduckgo   calculator but in vb.net it show me 847.999999 why is that .

this the Calcuatedemeter

```
 Private Function Calcuatedemeter(ByVal cartonnumber As Integer, ByVal platenumber As Integer) As String
        Dim result As String = ""
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        If cartonnumber > 0 Then
            sb.Append(cartonnumber)
            sb.Append(" Carton  ")
        End If
        If Not platenumber = 0 And cartonnumber > 0 Then
            sb.Append(" و  ")
        End If

        If platenumber > 0 Then
            sb.Append(" " & platenumber & " Peace ")
        End If
        result = sb.ToString

        Return result
    End Function
```

and iam gitting the Values From The DataBase Using this funcation

```
Function getInfoceramic(ByVal gsize As Double, ByVal gcarton As Integer, ByVal gname As String, ByVal gwidth As Double, ByVal glength As Double) As Double
    size = CDbl(gsize)
    cartonpak = gcarton
    name = gname
    width = gwidth
    length = glength
    platesize = (width / 100) * (length / 100)


End Function
```

Comment: i can't use round function because some time the remain will be calculated as pieces if there is remains this function was working fine in all my calculation  only in this values it give me like that ma by there is more values .

Comment: `SplitDouble` - what is this. `Calcuatedemeter` what is this? You're not showing us all the code

Comment: If I do `Dim result As Double = 1365.28 / 1.61` the result is 848, as expected. Something is going on in the code you're not showing us.

Comment: Hey @Alex i dont No why is That Happen here with me it give me 847.999999 not as should 848 and in my client pc the same result. i have add more of my code

Comment: WHAT IS SplitDouble???

Comment: @Alex: Try calculating `(1365.28/1.61)-848` instead. That gives me `-1.13686837721616E-13`. I suspect you are seeing a rounded result rather than the full floating point number. Taking off the integer part might reveal just the minor error.

Comment: If you need precision, then use the Decimal data type.

Comment: @Alex SplitDouble used to get the intger value and the floating point its built in function   in vb.net  ,

Comment: @TnTinMn iam reading about the math broken

Comment: @the_lotus i will change it to Decimal and See what happen

Comment: @ the_lotus it worked Fine And give me The 848 After I change it to Decimal

Comment: It is worth noting that you can still get similar problems with rounding errors while using decimal. Its just that the set of errors will be slightly different. eg 1/3 is still not accurately representable as a decimal so `1/3` can still cause these kind of weird rounding things.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the nature of double values, they aren't stored as exact values but instead they are stored as a non-precise approximation.

This is pretty well understand and the error assosciated (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)

For a work around if you know you're only dealing with 2 decimal places you could use integers and store it multiplied by 100, then only divide by 100 when you want to output the value.

Comment: presuming it will only ever be 2 decimal places is a pretty big leap of faith...

Comment: @user2366842 That's why I didn't presume, I said "IF", I was giving a conditional scenario based on the fact that the data provided was two decimal places. Might be useful might not, but I didn't say "Assuming you are dealing with 2 decimal places". 

In the same sense of saying "If it rains tomorrow, I'll wear a coat", I'm not presuming that it will rain tomorrow, am I?